# How to let Bash script extends User's PATH?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

At command line, my command `python3 -u jupterlab notebook` works perfectly as python locates at `/srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin/python3`.

Next, I have a bash script, say `/usr/local/share/python3-login`, its content is

```
#!/bin/bash -l
echo $PATH
exec python3 -u "$@"
```

My problem is when I call the script, I encountered an error where python3 not found `/usr/local/share/python3-login: line 3: exec: python3: not found`

I tried to debug by adding `echo $PATH` at line 2, and turned out PATH is `/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/game`, which python3 doesn't exist

How to let my bash script recognize `/srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin/python3`?

To add more context, I built a docker image with Ubuntu OS

Comment: Read the section _INVOCATION_ in the bash man page. It describes which files are processed by a bash login shell. Most likely, the PATH is set in one of those file to the value you observed. What's the reason that you want to run it as login shell?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`-l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell`
That means it will loads the various profile files as if you just logged in

Since `/srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin` does not look as a standard path one would see in an profile file, I suspect you do something more to get this in your $PATH in the first place.

solution 1: simply add whatever you do to get this path in your environment, into the script.

solution 2: simply don't use the `-l` argument in your shebang.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the full path:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
echo $PATH
exec /srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin/python3 -u "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the user's path, modify the `PATH` environment variable.

```sh
export PATH=/srv/conda/envs/notebook/bin/python3:$PATH
```